# How to autoclick a link within a div

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to autoclick the first link within a div after a short delay but my code isn't working. What's going wrong here?

```
//HTML
<div id="main">
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google link</a>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>

//Just checking that I selected the link
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("main");
var y = x.getElementsByTagName("a");

//Here's just checking I got the link
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
'The first link (index 0) inside "main" is: ' + y[0].href;

//Here's the timer
    window.setTimeout("autoClick()", 2000);

//And this is what isn't working...
function autoClick() {
var linkPage = y[0];
window.location.href = linkPage;
}
</script>
```

I'm obviously missing something pretty obvious, because the autoclick doesn't work, but can't see it for looking - can anyone see what elementary mistake I'm making please?

Comment: have you made sure that `y` is within scope and has value within the function .. It seems you're out of scope.  `y` and `x` should be set *within* the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have need to use `getAttribute('href')` in order to retrieve the href value. Your line should read:

```
window.location.href = linkPage.getAttribute('href');
```

You full code should look like (formatted and improved slightly):

```
<div id="main">
    <p>The first paragraph.</p>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google link</a>
    <p>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    let x = document.getElementById("main");
    let y = x.getElementsByTagName("a");

    // Test code...
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'The first link (index 0) inside "main" is: ' + y[0].href;

    // Auto click after 2 seconds...
    window.setTimeout(autoClick, 2000);

    function autoClick() {
        window.location.href = y[0].getAttribute('href');
    }

</script>
```

## Notes

- Use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
- You do not need the parentheses or quotes on call to the `autoClick` function
- No need to create the variable `linkPage`, simply use `y[0]`.

Comment: Thank you - that's sorted it!

Comment: @JackSamson - please accept the answer if it solves your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = linkPage.getAttribute('href')
```

Also

```
setTimeout(autoClick, 2000)
```

Comment: Welcome.  It could be nice if you mark as answer and vote up